# glTF file is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, server, three.js

I want to display a glTF file using Three.js. Due to CORS policy, I am using local server(Servez). When I am running it on Mozilla Firefox, it has no errors but still it is not showing anything. On doing same on Chrome, it is showing- "Not allowed to load local resource:". Even I have used the Chrome Web Server extension, but still results the same on both browsers.

> PS-I know that this is related to some security issues with Chrome but I do not want to override any security settings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>

    </script>

    <script type="module">

    import {GLTFLoader} from 'C:/Users/Prinzu/three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'C:/Users/Prinzu/three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

      let scene, camera, renderer;

      function init() {
       scene = new THREE.Scene();
       scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
       camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
       camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
       camera.position.x = 800;
       camera.position.y = 100;
       camera.position.z = 1000;
       controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
       controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);
       hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
       scene.add(hlight);
       directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
       directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
       directionalLight.castShadow = true;
       scene.add(directionalLight);
       light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
       light.position.set(0,300,500);
       scene.add(light);
       light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
       light2.position.set(500,100,0);
       scene.add(light2);
       light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
       light3.position.set(0,100,-500);
       scene.add(light3);
       light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
       light4.position.set(-500,300,500);
       scene.add(light4);
       renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
       renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
       document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
       let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
       loader.load('scene.gltf', function(gltf){
         car = gltf.scene.children[0];
         car.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
         scene.add(gltf.scene);
         animate();
       });
     }
     function animate() {
       renderer.render(scene,camera);
       requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     }
     init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your paths are all over the place

this

```
<script type="module" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script type="module">

import {GLTFLoader} from 'C:/Users/Prinzu/three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'C:/Users/Prinzu/three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

should be something closer to this

```
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from './three.js-master/build/three.module.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from './three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

Notice there is only one script tag. That it's loading `three.module.js` not `three.js` and it's loading it via `import`.

Then arrange your files something like

```
+-somefolder
  +-yourpage.html
  +-scene.gltf
  +-scene.bin
  +-three.js-master
    +-build
    | +-three.module.js
    +-examples
      +-jsm
        +-controls
        | +-OrbitControls.js
        +-loaders
          +-GLTFLoader.js
```

In other words, put all the files for your project under `somefolder`. Then serve `somefolder` and load `yourpage.html`

Also `new THREE.OrbitControls(...` and `new THREE.GLTFLoader(...` become `new OrbitControls(...` and `new GLTFLoader(...`. You can see when you import them they are available directly, not on the THREE object.

Comment: Totally agreed with you sir, But now it is  showing that GLTFLoader is not  a constructor. @gman

Comment: It' s not `new THREE.GLTFLoader` when done this way, it's just `new GLTFLoader`